# Synchronous buck battery charging circuit using totem pole gate driver

Tags: buck, boost, buck-boost

Background - We are trying to develop a very low cost buck (day time)/boost (night time) converter for charging LFP batteries (day time) and powering LED (night time). Due to cost impact we are trying to avoid half bridge gate drivers if possible at all.

The circuit - below is the simulation circuit of our buck converter, which will work as a booster for 18 V in night time.
Input - 25 V, 6.5 A
Battery (fitted with BMS - 12.8 V)
[image]

High side driver:
[image]

Low side driver:
[image]

PWM (deadtime of 2 us will be managed by MCU PWM generator) - 20 kHz.

Output:
[image]
High side & low side gate waveforms:
[image]
Gate to source:
[image]
Power dissipation for Q2
[image]
Inductor current:
[image]

Issue -  we had to put R6 (3.3 kΩ) on high side driver & R14 (330 Ω) on low side driver to reduce the current flowing out through Q2 & Q4 PNP respectively during PWM fall (around 180 mA) on each side due to gate capacitor discharge, which totals to around 6 W of power dissipation on high side considering high side gate voltage is coming around 35 V with reference to ground. But commonly available SMD transistors (SOT-23 pack) are around 0.3-0.5 W range. which seems not feasible to use and hence we had to introduce the resistors, but in-turn to overcome slow gate capacitor discharge we had to increase deadtime around 2 us to reduce the shoot through current due to the high side and low side overlap, and it is impacting the efficiency.

Question - are we missing anything here? We considered using MOSFETs for driving circuit but again the cheap SMD packs will be of similar power rating. What are we missing?

Comment: Could you please put gate-source voltage waveforms for hi-side? It'll be more meaningful.

Comment: Why not return high-side turn-off current (i.e. Q2-C) to source instead of GND? What are your power figures from, simulation or empirical? Peak power doesn't mean anything, average does; you would need quite large gates and/or fast switching to burn up SOT-23s.

Comment: @RohatKılıç - Vgs waveform added, thanks!

Comment: @TimWilliams - added the average power dissipation figure for Q2, it is around 20mW, which is far lower than the rated one! Can we then conclude that the peak power will not be of any major concern? on the other idea of grounding to source , I will run few more simulations and get back here, many thanks!

Comment: You may also find that 2N7002 has quite a lot more capacitance than BC847, which can be substituted in by adding some base or emitter bias resistors.  Likewise pull-up resistors can be replaced with PNP CCSs. Should be able to get dead time to a few 100s ns this way.